# Calculate the sum of values of group by columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am facing a prolem to sum all values of column on which I have done group by.

```
df2 = df.groupby(['Courses','Duration'])['Fee'].sum()  
print(df2)
```

then I got below output.

```
Courses  Duration
Hadoop   35days      25000
         55days      23000
Pandas   60days      26000
PySpark  50days      25000
Python   40days      24000
         50days      22000
Spark    30days      22000
         55days      25000
```

So I would like to ask you that how would I calculate sum of Hadoop (25000+23000) and similary for Pandas, PySpark, Python, and Spark?

Comment: df2 = df.groupby(['Courses'])['Fee'].sum(), doesn't this work?

Answer (score 0):

simply remove 'Duration' from your `groupby()`

```
df2 = df.groupby(['Courses'])['Fee'].sum()
```